# IPython notebook's icon on button don't show up in browser

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I run my IPython Notebook server on a Guest OS(Fedora) in vmware, and I access it using Chrome on my Host OS(windows).

But the icons on the buttons don't show up. Nothing on the button.(Sorry, I really want to post an image here but I don't have enough reputation to do that.)

I search google for a long time but can't find the answer.

Would someone know the reason? or just give me some clue.